# .htaccess redirect all of the html to php

Tags: php, .htaccess

Here is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule (.*)\.html              $1.php [R=301,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

It should go to `wireless.php` when I access `wireless.html`.

But the weird thing is it go to `404.php` when I access `wireless.html`,

and it go to `wireless.php` when I access `wireless1.html`, `wirelessk.html`, `wireless9.html`, etc...

Any idea? Thx.

Comment: Q1. Is this the only .htaccess or do you have another? Q2. Is this the only code in this .htaccess? If you have some other code then please post it in question? Q3. What is location of above .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

Forgot a `^`

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [L,R=301]
```